# Getting org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property, even property is exactly same

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to execute simple criteria but getting "org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property".
Actually I have to apply condition on ProcessInstanceJPA but it is not recognizing processInstanceJPA in ExpenseHeaderJPA.

Criteria:

```
    List<ExpenseHeaderJPA> expsensHeaderList= session.createCriteria(ExpenseHeaderJPA.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("processInstanceJPA.processInstanceId", new Long(1))
            .list();
```

ProcessInstaceJPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name="process_instance")
public class ProcessInstanceJPA {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="process_instance_id")
    private Long processInstanceId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="expense_header_id")
    /*@OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn*/
    private ExpenseHeaderJPA expenseHeaderJPA;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="voucher_status_id")
    private VoucherStatusJPA voucherStatusJPA;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="pending_at")
    private EmployeeJPA pendingAt;

    public Long getProcessInstanceId() {
        return processInstanceId;
    }

    public void setProcessInstanceId(Long processInstanceId) {
        this.processInstanceId = processInstanceId;
    }

    public ExpenseHeaderJPA getExpenseHeaderJPA() {
        return expenseHeaderJPA;
    }

    public void setExpenseHeaderJPA(ExpenseHeaderJPA expenseHeaderJPA) {
        this.expenseHeaderJPA = expenseHeaderJPA;
    }

    public VoucherStatusJPA getVoucherStatusJPA() {
        return voucherStatusJPA;
    }

    public void setVoucherStatusJPA(VoucherStatusJPA voucherStatusJPA) {
        this.voucherStatusJPA = voucherStatusJPA;
    }

    public EmployeeJPA getPendingAt() {
        return pendingAt;
    }

    public void setPendingAt(EmployeeJPA pendingAt) {
        this.pendingAt = pendingAt;
    }
}
```

ExpenseHeaderJPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name="expense_header")
public class ExpenseHeaderJPA {


@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name="expense_header_id")
private Long expenseHeaderId;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="expenseHeaderJPA",fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<ExpenseDetailJPA> expenseDetailJPA; 

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="expenseHeaderJPA",fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<ProcessHistoryJPA> processHistoryJPA;

@OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="expenseHeaderJPA",fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
private ProcessInstanceJPA processInstanceJPA;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private EmployeeJPA employeeJPA;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "voucher_status")
private VoucherStatusJPA voucherStatusJPA;

@Column(name="start_date")
private Calendar startDate;

@Column(name="end_date")
private Calendar endDate;

@Column(name="title")
private String title;

@Column(name="purpose")
private String purpose;

public Long getExpenseHeaderId() {
    return expenseHeaderId;
}

public void setExpenseHeaderId(Long expenseHeaderId) {
    this.expenseHeaderId = expenseHeaderId;
}

public Calendar getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Calendar startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Calendar getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(Calendar endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPurpose() {
    return purpose;
}

public void setPurpose(String purpose) {
    this.purpose = purpose;
}

public List<ExpenseDetailJPA> getExpenseDetailJPA() {
    return expenseDetailJPA;
}

public void setExpenseDetailJPA(List<ExpenseDetailJPA> expenseDetailJPA) {
    this.expenseDetailJPA = expenseDetailJPA;
}

public EmployeeJPA getEmployeeJPA() {
    return employeeJPA;
}

public void setEmployeeJPA(EmployeeJPA employeeJPA) {
    this.employeeJPA = employeeJPA;
}

public VoucherStatusJPA getVoucherStatusJPA() {
    return voucherStatusJPA;
}

public List<ProcessHistoryJPA> getProcessHistoryJPA() {
    return processHistoryJPA;
}

public void setProcessHistoryJPA(List<ProcessHistoryJPA> processHistoryJPA) {
    this.processHistoryJPA = processHistoryJPA;
}

public void setVoucherStatusJPA(VoucherStatusJPA voucherStatusJPA) {
    this.voucherStatusJPA = voucherStatusJPA;
}

public ProcessInstanceJPA getProcessInstanceJPA() {
    return processInstanceJPA;
}

    public void setProcessInstanceJPA(ProcessInstanceJPA processInstanceJPA) {
        this.processInstanceJPA = processInstanceJPA;
    }

}
```

ExpenseHeaderJPA is parent table and ProcessInstanceJPA is child table. There is OnetoOne mapping between them. When i am trying to apply restriction on any property of ProcessInstaceJPA, i getting invalid property error.

MySQL database structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `expense_header` (
  `expense_header_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
....
....

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    CREATE TABLE `process_instance` (
  `process_instance_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `expense_header_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
 ...
 ...
)
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You're not using JPA, so no idea why you call things after it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all what you whant to do, but it seems that you want a join, not an equals.

I think that the Restrictions class does not have that option, you could do it with a CriteriaBuilder.

You can do something like this:

```
//you should initialize this variables depending on how you are working with hibernate
private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
private CriteriaQuery<ExpenseHeaderJPA> criteria;
private Root<ExpenseHeaderJPA> root;
private Predicate exp;
exp.getExpressions().add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(processInstanceJPA).get(processInstanceId), new Long(1)));

this.criteria.where(exp);
return session.createQuery().getResultList(); //I don't know what you have in session, but you should be able to create the query.
```

Comment: I want apply condition on processInstanceJPA . But it is showing above error

Comment: what condition do you want to apply? please be more specific. Have you tried this?

Comment: ExpenseHeaderJPA is parent table and ProcessInstanceJPA is child table. There is OnetoOne mapping between them.
When i am trying to apply restriction on any property of ProcessInstaceJPA, i getting invalid property error.